# How is this c function decrementing my counter?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, call

I have the following code:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
  ...
  printf("i = %d\n",i);
  rtdb_pull(rtdb, buf, &ncenter);
  printf("i = %d\n",i);
  ...
}
```

When I run it, it goes through just fine while i=0, but as soon as i=1, the rtdb_pull function seems to decrement the counter, so I end up stuck in a loop. How is this possible? I don't pass i to rtdb_pull, nor does rtdb_pull use a variable called i.

If I do this, everything works just fine:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
  ...
  printf("i = %d\n",i);
  int j = i;
  rtdb_pull(rtdb, buf, &ncenter);
  i = j;
  printf("i = %d\n",i);
  ...
}
```

For the record, I am using gcc 4.7.3 on Ubuntu 13.04 and compiling with ANSI c. I do not get any related warnings from the compiler.

Comment: It's possible that the error is somewhere else in your code and the assembly instructions do not stop executing until that line and it's merely a coincidence.

Comment: Probably, `rtdb_pull` writes to memory it shouldn't write to, namely `i`. Running it under valgrind may locate the offending write.

Comment: What does `rtdb_pull()` do? Where is `rtdb`, `buf`, and `&ncenter` in relation to `i`?

Comment: @JacobPollack - how would I test that?

Comment: Use valgrind like @DanielFischer suggested. It's likely due to that and the assembly instructions continue executing until it realizes that something went wrong. The error is exactly as he described and his debugging recommendation is quite good.

Comment: @DanielFischer - I do not know anything about valgrind. I will look into that if there is no other proposed solution that works.

Comment: @jxh - rtdb_pull queries a runtime database. rtdb is an integer that identifies the database, buf is a string telling what value I want to get back and ncenter is a pointer to where I want to store that value.

Comment: @DanielFischer - I have installed valgrind. How can I get it to monitor when this particular variable is modified?

Comment: @Pinyaka: Dynamically allocate `ncenter` instead of making it a variable. Then, run the program under `valgrind`. Just run your program like you would normally, but precede it with `valgrind`.

Comment: @jxh - Dynamically allocating ncenter fixed the problem. I'm tried running valgring with and without the fix, but I don't understand what the output is telling me.

I should also point out that I'm modifying some 30 year old legacy code, so even without this error, valgrind is spitting out enough errors to use up my scrollback buffer. I tried searching the logfile for terms like rtdb and efp (part of the name of my function), but didn't get any hits on either.

Anyway, if you want to put your solution below, I'll vote for it and mark the problem as solved.

Comment: Please add the code that's causing the problem: `rtdb_pull()`!

Comment: @Pinyaka See my answer: A non-targeted change of the code may let this bug disappear, but won't fix the root cause.  Be very careful, it may bite again.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that `rtdb_pull()` is causing this, because otherwise the compiler would be broken.

What's happening is that `rtdb_pull()` is overwriting `i` caused by a programming mistake in this function.  Coincidently `i` is overwritten with `0`.  Depending on where things end up in memory, your malicious function could have been overwriting other variables, or none at all.

It appears that your erroneous code does not overwrite `j`, and that's just another coincidence.

Where this happens, can only be anwered when you supply the code of `rtdb_pull()` plus the code where `rtdb`, `buf`, and `ncenter` are defined and allocated.

Changing the code, like dynamically allocating `ncenter` as you wrote, may make this problem disappear.  But it won't fix the root cause.  So be very careful, it may bite again!

Answer (score 0):

If your rtdb_pull() is a function of unmanaged assembly body and it has forgotten push-pop backups then possibly your loop-counter(which is better in a register rather than memory) is being mangled by the assembly code of rtdb_.

If the assembly's register backup is automatically done, then the error is outside of assembly body(rtdb_pull() may be a simple C function? then error must be an undefined behavioral memory-access)

Comment: Assuming the error is in the code the OP gave, the error is in function `rtdb_pull()` that the OP did not give? (note that assembly language is not required for C code doing strange things)

Comment: Then it is a mis-written variable name or undefined beh. in the function.

Comment: It is neither undefined nor mis-written.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have posted a code snippet and so there might some other reason or consideration as to why this is happening!, but the parameter `rtdb` looks suspiciously like the address of the function `rtdb`?

```
   rtdb_pull(rtdb, buf, &ncenter);
```

Is this true, if so, does `rtdb` have access to i?

Comment: rtdb is an integer that identifies a runtime database, not a function. More fully, none of the parameters are functions, just an integer, string and pointer to an integer respectively.

Comment: @Pinyaka would you mind either posting code as-is if its a few lines, or distilling the problem to its essentials and posting that code?

Comment: I have condensed it to the best of my ability. It's a part of a ginormous legacy code package, so for example, rtdb_pull is nothing but other function calls to different parts of the package.

It seems like there was a memory leak and changing int ncenter to int *ncenter and making appropriate adjustments has fixed the problem.

Comment: I'd suspect `buf` as well. Maybe it's allocated too short, and being overwritten bumping into `i` on the stack?

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that `rtdb_pull(rtdb, buf, &ncenter)` writes its results into `buf`, and possibly `ncenter`, I'd want to see how those are allocated. If `buf` is a local, for example, and has too few bytes allocated to it, the function might be overflowing the buffer, bumping into other variables on the stack, including `i`. Let's see those declarations and relevant assignments.